# Can I 'decorate' a simple `qtree`?

Tags: tikz-trees, tikz-qtree, qtree

I have the following code which represents a package `qtree` tree:

```
\Tree[.${((q \to (\neg r)) \land (\neg(p\lor q)))}$ 
        [.${(q \to (\neg r))}$ 
            [.$q$ ]
            [.${(\neg r)}$ $r$ ] 
        ]
        [.${(\neg (p \lor q))}$
            [.${(p \lor q)}$  
                [.$p$ ]
                [.$q$ ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Which gives a result like:

[image: qtree]

The result is correct and exactly what I expected, however, I wish I could decorate it to make it more stylized and make it easier to read. Concretely I would like to configure the separation between nodes of the tree and convert the lines into arrows.

The result I would like would be like:

[image: desired result]

Is it possible to do this with the `qtree` library? How could I do it in the simplest way? Should I use `tkiz-qtree` or `tkiz-tree`? and how?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- it seems that `tkiz-qtree` package is deliberately designed to produce diagrams as you show in the first image
- what you like to achieve, can be easy done by use of `forest` package.

**Edit:**

- Added forgotten arrows head as remained me @Jasper Habicht. Now added.

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
  
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {math content, 
            edge=->,
            l sep=5mm,
            s sep=7mm,
            }
[((q \to (\neg r)) \land (\neg(p\lor q))) 
    [(q \to (\neg r))
        [q]
        [(\neg r)
            [r]
        ]
    ]
    [(\neg (p \lor q))
        [(p \lor q)
            [p]
            [q]
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:**
For arrows head you can defined by use of `arrows.meta` TikZ library. For example with

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}     % <---

\begin{document}
  
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {math content,
            edge=-Straight Barb, % <---
            l sep=5mm,
            s sep=7mm,
            }
% rest the same as before
```

tree become:

[image]

Comment: Maybe add `edge=->` for arrows.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, you are right, I oversee arrows head. Thank to you now added!

Comment: Is the `edge=->` correctly indicated? When adding it to get the arrows I get compilation error. without it, no problems but not arrows!

Comment: @balon, yes. However you may try to write edge as `edge={->},`  at the first example and as `edge={-Straight Barb},˛` at the second one.